# Exception to be thrown in case static variable has not been initialized

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a `static` method `concatString(String source)` in a `class` which takes `String` argument "source" . The same class has another `static string` variable "target". The "target" string get initialized in another static method called `init()`. Now if the user calls `concatString()` method before calling `init()` method , i need to throw `exception` .

Can anyone help me with waht `exception` should i `throw` from `concatString()`
I think we cannot throw `IIlegalArgumentException` since there is nothing wrong with the argument.Should it be `null pointer exception`?

Comment: That looks like a design smell. You should avoid non-final static fields in general, and design your API to make such a situation impossible. Like, for example, return an object from the `init()` method, and add the `concatString()` method to this object. That way, it would be impossible to concat before initializing.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.IllegalStateException` might help you

---

PS.
See also [static Initializers in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). Maybe it can help you with initialization of your static fields.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a requirement to call `init()` on your class users.   Either have the code in `init()` called during the class construction, or  call `init()`  when `concatString()` is called, like this:

```
public static String concatString(String source)
{
    init();
    //concat string code.
    return concatedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom exception for yourself.
That will make your exception hold some info in your context.

```
class MyConcatException extends Exception{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyConcatException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void MyMethod() throws MyConcatException
    {
        //do something
        throw new MyConcatException("target is not init");
    }
```

And you will get:

```
MyConcatException: target is not init
    at Main.MyMethod(Main.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```